# Incorrect use of Noun Clause?

Tags: grammar-identification

In a textbook for German language (*Aspekte neu, Mittelstufe Deutsch, Teil 1 B2*), I found this sentence:

> Wer erwischt wurde, **der** bekam zunächst Hausverbot.

To me, this is a clear use of [Noun Clause](https://editorsmanual.com/articles/forms-of-subject/#noun-clause-as-subject) similarly in English. But the problem is why there is a **der** in front of **bekam**?

The "*Wer erwischt wurde*" should serve as the subject of the sentence.

*** **Updated** ***

More examples in the same text:

> Wen Fahim Yusufzai der Polizei übergeben hatte, **dem** begegnete er am nächsten Tag garantiert erneut im Einkaufszentrum.

> Wen Probleme plagen, **der** hat die Möglichkeit, jederzeit mit ihm zu sprechen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

German in general allows correlative constructions where two fronted elements are paired, yet perform a single function:

> [ Der Hans, ] [ der ] kommt erst morgen wieder.
>
> [ Wenn es nicht anders geht, ] [ dann ] bleiben wir eben zu Hause.
>
> [ Wo eine Wille ist, ] [ da ] ist auch ein Weg.

Either of the two elements can be left out.

> Was ist mit Hans? – [ Der ] kommt erst morgen wieder.
> Bist du ganz allein im Büro? – Ja, [ der Hans ] kommt erst morgen wieder.

However, in a cased language such as German, having two elements present allows for a case mismatch.

> [ Wer das nicht will, ] [ dem ] muss man Alternativen anbieten.

*Dem* functions as the dative object of *anbieten*, *wer* as the subject of *will*. Leaving out *dem* is impossible, presumably because nominative *wer* without resumptive *dem* would lead listeners up the garden path.

German allows for constructions that are impossible in English. (Note that while the Wittgenstein quote is usually translated literally, I don't think it is idiomatic English.)

> [ Wovon man nicht sprechen kann, ] [ darüber ] muss man schweigen.
>
> [ Wer nicht mehr motiviert ist, ] [ mit dem ] sollte man reden.

Answer (score 1):

das "der" kann auch weggelassen werden, allerdings klingt es besser für mich wenn es da ist. Ich denke es wird verständlicher wenn man den Satzteil umdreht (es muss dann leicht abgewandelt werden):

- Der, der erwischt wurde, bekam zunächst Hausverbot.
- Der, welcher erwischt wurde,...
- The one, who got caught,...

If you would omit "the one" here it would be strange aswell.

Greetings, Biene :)